# Adding comma to coordinates in TSV file

Tags: csv, coordinates

I've a large TSV file that I'm viewing through MS Excel. I have a column showing arrays of coordinates. Unfortunately, the database from which the coords were taken did not include a comma separator between lat and long. The coords are formatted thus:

[[4.47917 51.9225],[-3.179559057 55.951719876],[-3.17055 55.9721],[-3.297777777 55.625],[-3.355388888 55.752611111]]

Whereas I need them formatted like:

[[4.47917, 51.9225],[-3.179559057, 55.951719876],[-3.17055, 55.9721],[-3.297777777, 55.625],[-3.355388888, 55.752611111]]

Is there a quick way that I can add these commas (the TSV has too many values for me to manually correct them).

I'm v much finding my way with this stuff so any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, lucky you  `Ctrl+H` to replace and replace   with `,` . Replace space with coma followed by space.